# word request (name for an MP3 file)

Tags: word-request

I have an English coach and he created a new English-learning program where he teaches pronunciation, rhythm, intonation and flow to help his students, including me, sound more natural. So, every time before making explanation videos, he sends everybody a lesson assignment, which can be a news story, a job interview, a dialogue, a promotional pitch or something of that nature (the assignment is not too long, usually 6-8 sentences on average). Your job as a student is to prepare and record yourself reading the assignment while doing your best to sound as perfect as possible (you've got about a week to do that before he gets back to you with explanation material). After you're done, you e-mail your MP3 recording to him, so that he can see what kind of mistakes everybody made which helps him better prepare for the class. That's the general idea of the class. And now I'm trying to come up with good names for my lesson files.

**Lesson 1. Part 1 - Pronunciation.wmv** -- the name of the first video file

**Lesson 1. Part 2 - Rhythm, Flow and Intonation.wmv** -- the name of the second video file

**Audio lesson files** – this is the folder for the two audio files which are basically audio tracks from the lesson videos

**Lesson assignment.pdf** – PDF file with the lesson assignment

But, my question is really about the following, there's also an MP3 file that comes along with each lesson where you can hear him read the assignment (he's just reading the text with natural and perfect pronunciation). And that's basically what it's all about—it's about that all-important file which shows you the perfect way that you should eventually be able to read the assignment. I'm kind of at a loss as to what to call that file. The only thing I could think of was *lesson story*, but that obviously doesn't sound very professional, does it? Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "you can hear him read the assignment", is he giving instructions how to do the assignment, or just reading the text of the lesson itself?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `example.mp3` (or `coach's reading example.mp3`) or `assignment.mp3` should work.

Comment: To keep with your naming scheme, try "Lesson 1. Part 1 - Pronunciation Example.mp3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in-case you'd prefer something other than some of the suggestions already here:

> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Pronunciation Guide
>
> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Solution/Pronunciation
>
> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Final Audio
>
> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Reading Aloud
>
> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Text pronunciation
>
> Lesson 1. Part 3 - Audio Guide

You could use most things here, I'm not sure that anything you'd think of would shock the users to any extreme. Personally, I think that the ones that indicate that the file contains audio are the best names.

All the best!

Comment: To the downvoter, mind saying why?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities are **Standard Reading** and **Exemplar**.

That said, you should be aware that "(he's just reading the text with natural and perfect pronunciation)" is a bit alarming. There is no universally accepted "perfect". At the very least, British and American Standard accents are well-regarded (think BBC and American news broadcasters), but the two are instantly distinguishable to a native speaker. And while I can't speak for the Brits, within American speech patterns the two regional accents "Southern drawl" and "Texas drawl" are both generally accepted as valid ways of speaking.

Comment: +1 *Exemplar* is an apt word here, and your point about variety is important.

Answer (score 2):

> Reference.mp3

You compare your efforts to the file, so this name might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Lesson 1. Study Guide - Full Text Reading.mp3

Sounds like you are just providing this for the student to learn from, so to me it's a study aid or study guide.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's clearly a [dictation (sense #1)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/DICTATION). So, a few choices could be...

> dictation.mp3 
>  master_dictation.mp3 
>  coach_dictation.mp3 and so on...

Comment: I like the word "master". "Lesson 1. Coach Master Reading.mp3" sounds best to me so far. More suggestions are still welcome and, I'd even say, needed.

Comment: Yes, blending all my suggestions gives you the most suitable file name I guess.

Comment: I think "Lesson 1. Coach's Master Reading" sounds a little bit better because this way, the grammar is better.

Comment: I won't mind the previous version. Attributive nouns! Something like: England Football Team Coach! :)

Comment: This could be useful - http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/111108possattrib.htm

Answer (score 0):

***"Audio Lesson"*** may be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson 1 - model.mp3

I have a few suggestions.

- listen to a slowed-down version of the model recording a few times.
- try singing the reading passage.
- try shouting the reading passage -- in grad school, I had a friend from China who practiced his Russian this way!
- try looking at your mouth with a small mirror while you recite sentences from the passage.
- try reading the passage in unison while listening to the model recording.

See if any of these loosen you up!

Answer (score 0):

Try **model answer**. This gives the impression that the file is a completely perfect representation that could not be improved on, and that it should be used by those looking to better their own answers or see where they tripped up.